# Get OG administrator users from Rules

Tags: organic-groups, emails, rules

I want to send an e-mail to all group administrators when a user joins a group.

Rules and OG come with this functionality out of the box, but unfortunately the default rule is set to only e-mail the group manager. I want to e-mail all of the group administrators for the group.

I've just spent a frustrating few hours trying to get this to work. I can manage to make a variable with the groups members, but then struggle to filter this down. I know I can call og_get_users_by_roles() to get all of the information I need but then struggle to insert that information into a Rules variable.

Some help?

Comment: Duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35026/og-group-content-notification-for-group-administrators?