# OG group content notification for group administrators

Tags: 7, rules, organic-groups

I'm using Drupal 7.12 with OG 7.x-1.3 and Rules 7.x-2.0.

There is a pre-installed rule that I'm using for group notifications which is "OG group content notification". This sends out an email to all group members when new group content is created. I want to modify this so it only sends out emails to group members who have an "administrator" role for that group.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I did see that it's possible for me to get a list of group managers instead of group members but I don't want just the manager I want all the group administrators.

Many thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8338/get-og-administrator-users-from-rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task cannot be done in an obvious way. A piece of content can be content of several groups. If a user is admin in the first group, but not in the second group, should he receive the email or not? If a user is an admin in both groups, should he receive the email twice?
You'll have to think about that first before one can give a precise answer.

Either way, my guess is that one should create either a rule component "Send email if group admin" that receives a user and a group as variables, or one should create a view of group admins that the rule loops over. Do ask me for details if you still need the advice.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, that is very helpful.